# Why does this regex fail on the last text input containing punctuation characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

As demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/beardedgrandma/x8fy9/

this regex:

```
/([\w .]*)[~]([\w .]*)(\(|Release Date)/
```

fails on this text input:

```
<div>Watergate Files: Bernstein & Woodward ~ Alastair Campbell (Author) (19)Release Date: Decemb</div>
```

**Presumably this is because of the punctuation in the title**:

```
Watergate Files: Bernstein & Woodward
```

**How to correct this?**

Comment: & is not valid in HTML. You have to escape it as `&apm;` By the way, you have to escape almost every character in HTML, at least in valid HTML, such as "déja-vù" becoming `d&eacute;ja-v&ugrave;`.

Comment: you deleted the original question? not cool - I want my rep!

Comment: @Camino: That is absolutely wrong. `&` doesn't need to be escaped if not followed by an alpha-numeric character, and you don't need to escape any characters that are supported by the character set the HTML is written in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
/([^~]+)~([^~(]+?)(?:\(|Release Date)/
```